# How to open a database (.crypt8) file?

Tags: whatsapp, android-database

I have to open a database (.crypt8) file in my computer. I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5WViK3dTiAo), but this method it requires root access to work. How could I achieve this?